# Difference between materialize-css and material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui, materialize

I went through the home page of [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/) and [materialUI](https://material-ui.com/). The first one mentions **A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design** and the later one mentions **React components that implement Google's Material Design**. Both of them implements material design and both of them give me components to use. Where exactly is the difference between both of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both materialize and material UI implement Google's Material Design But in two different way. For instance grid system is one of differences.

As material UI mention in it's documentation, materialize has these differences :

1. Materialize supports a wider range of browsers than Material-UI does, for instance, they support IE 10 while we only support IE 11. Only supporting IE 11 allows us to take full advantage of the flexbox layout. IE 10 has many issues with flexbox.
2. Materialize uses SCSS, a styling architecture Material-UI moved away from 2 years ago.
   (https://material-ui.com/getting-started/comparison/#materialize)

Although material UI is the most popular React component library because it has a large set of React components.

Some communities like gem, meteor and ember have ability to include Materialize their projects.

I had experience with using materialize with angularjs. materialize provides directives for using materializecss features in angularjs (https://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/). most of them work properly but `input-field` directive cause problem in application performance.

Comment: Can you explain in detail how to use Js functions of materializeCSS like `caraousel`, `sidenav`, etc. in React without jQuery but with the help of vanillaJS

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke Sorry, I have no experience with React.

Comment: Can I use both of them in my React project? Sorry for the too mainstream question.

Comment: Yes you can technically use both of them in your project but maybe some conflicts occur and some components can't show properly. in my opinion one of them is enough and you can customize components that want to change